# Why does my jQuery slideDown/slideUp 'wear out'?

Tags: jquery

At [the site I'm developing](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/), I have some `div`s which are loaded by AJAX. They consist of a picture (displayed) and some text (hidden). Using jQuery's `$.live()` method, I make the text slide down when the mouse hovers over the picture, and then slide back up when the mouse leaves it.

However, after this is repeated several times (especially if in rapid succession), the text div doesn't expand to its full height any more - more often than not, its height changes to a single pixel.

My JS code is as follows:

```
$(".rColOffer").live({
  'mouseenter':function(){
    $(".rColOffer_text",this).stop(true).delay(200).slideDown(200);
  },
  'mouseleave':function(){
    $(".rColOffer_text",this).stop(true).slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

And the HTML structure goes something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <div class=box>
        <div class=picture>
        <div class=text>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li> more of the same... </li>
  <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

*(I know putting a `div` inside an `a` tag is bad practice, but the problem manifests even if I replace the `<a><div>...</div></a>` with an `a` which has `display:block`)*

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2X7Gt/7/) displaying the problem.

Comment: You can use <span> inside of <a> and it will be valid.

Comment: Just a side note, don't use live. Use delegate or if you are using jquery 1.7+ use .on()

Comment: @TomášLištiak Hmm, you're right - I had completely neglected the fact that, even though I had replaced the `<a><div>` with an `<a>`, this does nothing about other `divs`. Replacing them with `<span>`s behaves a bit differently, but doesn't seem to exhibit the same problem. Just might be on to something...

Comment: @Matt - Why, what's wrong with it? I've had some problems with `.on()` before, so I decided to stick to `.live()` for the time being. Might consider reworking it later on, though.

Comment: @egasimus .live is deprecated because it's slow. on() is a little more focused and doesn't have to scan an entire DOM to bind an event to a node. I updated my answer with .on() method, i would highly recommend using it.

Comment: @Matt - It seems, though, that `.on()` only works when I put it the onLoad event, doesn't it? And I'm trying to stay away from that - I guess it's for no good reason...

Comment: @egasimus Why would you stay away from the onload event? You can get code trying to load before the full DOM is even loaded and you will get stuff that just wont work. You should always use the ready or onload events.

Comment: @Matt, well, that's the problem event delegation remedied, I thought; I read it somewhere, too. There are many elements in my site which rely on JS to work, so I'm aiming for the pages to become responsive as early as possible. When I use `.live()`, I always give the selector a context, which I hope helps a little.

Comment: @egasimus yea even with live it could probably mess up. If a DOM element loaded before the .live listener was activated, i don't think the that element will work, at least not until another element of that same type shows up, then live will probably pick up the previous one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do .stop(true, true) instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/2X7Gt/8/

with .on()

http://jsfiddle.net/2X7Gt/9/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed it.